# SD card is titled "RECOVERY" and only has 1GB after using RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card, micro-sd-card

I was using a Raspberry PI 2 Model B, and I installed NOOBS. I selected and installed Raspbian, and I used my Pi for about 24 hours before I decided to re-install the OS. When I plugged in my micro SD card, I deleted all of the files inside. I'm not sure if this happened before or after I deleted the files, but my SD card was renamed "RECOVERY" and it went from 8GB to only 1GB storage. How can I fix my SD card?

NOTE: When I plugged the card into my mac, there were two Disks that were on my desktop, one of them was titled "BOOT", the other was titled "RECOVERY".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry pi systems use multiple partitions on the SD card but windows only looks at the first parititon.

If you want to put the card back into service for other things you will need to reset the partition table on the card. I belive the SD card associations formatter tool will do this if you select the "format size adjustment" option.